# Change output of wp_nav_menu();

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

Is it possible to change the wp_nav_menu(); output from:

```
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
    </ul>
```

to this:

```
    <ul>
       <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
       <a href="#"><li>Browse</li></a>
    </ul>
```

*-Thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. You'll have to [Using a custom Walker class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_custom_Walker_class) to achieve that. Anyway, may I ask why you're trying to implement this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will take a look at it.

I would like to do this due to some css...